# is it possible to redirect to another webpage after playing an animation with just html and css?

Tags: html, css

I want to create a kinda landing page where you can click on a button and an animation will play and then right after it will take you to another page, basically like a link with an animation before it change page

Comment: Have you tried anything? Technically the answer is yes.

Comment: @Kyle Technically yes? I fail so see a way adding a delay without using javascript. Please enlighten me :)

Comment: @KilianStinson That's where the _technically_ part of yes comes in ;)

Comment: so basically it cannot be done with just html and css, if I understood this

Answer (score 0):

You can use meta-refreshes to load another page without the use of javascript. This causes the browser to refresh the page with the given url (if any) after a given amount of time. Please note that using this method with a short delay could cause the user's back-button to "break"; i.e. the user wants to go back but is immediatly forwarded. This is (one of) the reason(s) this method is frowned upon.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1; url=http://stackoverflow.com/">
</head>
<body>
  <div>Your annimation to keep the user occupied.</div>
</body>
</html>
```